# Generic class variable in Python with metaclass and concrete base class

Tags: python, generics, type-hinting, mypy

Hi I have a problem with typing of Generic class attribute.

I simplified my example and I have a code like this:

```py
import typing

T = typing.TypeVar("T", bound="Model")

class QuerySet(typing.Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, models_cls: typing.Type[T]):
        self.model_cls = models_cls

    def get(self) -> T:
        return self.model_cls()

class BaseModel:  # <= external class imported from 3rd party lib
    pass

class BaseMetaclass(type):  # <= external meta class imported from 3rd party lib
    pass

class Metaclass(BaseMetaclass):
    def __new__(mcs: typing.Any, name: str, bases: typing.Any, attrs: dict):
        new_model = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        if hasattr(new_model, 'Meta'):
            new_model.objects = QuerySet(new_model)  # type: ignore
        return new_model

class NewBaseModel(BaseModel, metaclass=Metaclass):
    pass

class Model(NewBaseModel):
    pass

class MyModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        concrete = True

new_model = MyModel.objects.get()  # line 36 error - "Type[MyModel]" has no attribute "objects"
reveal_type(new_model)  # <= This should be of type MyModel but is Any
```

I tried typing QuerySet in a metaclass:

```py
class Metaclass(BaseMetaclass):
    def __new__(mcs: typing.Any, name: str, bases: typing.Any, attrs: dict):
        new_model = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)
        if hasattr(new_model, 'Meta'):
            new_model.objects = QuerySet[new_model](new_model) # error - Variable "new_model" is not valid as a type
        return new_model
```

I tried also adding type hints on Model class:

```py
class Model(typing.Generic[T], NewBaseModel):
    if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
        objects: QuerySet[T] # how to type this if I cannot rely on __init__ and __new__ as its a classvar
    class Meta:
        concrete = True
```

But the result is the same -> reveal_type is always Any as QuerySet T is never inferred/resolved?
Any help appreciated!

**EDIT: What I tried that didn't help**

Making Metaclass Generic:

```py
# not helping
class Metaclass(typing.Generic[T], BaseMetaclass):
    def __new__(  # type: ignore
            mcs: typing.Type[T], name: str, bases: typing.Any, attrs: dict
    ) -> typing.Type[T]:
        new_model = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)  # type: ignore
        if hasattr(new_model, 'Meta'):
            new_model.objects = QuerySet[T](new_model)
        return typing.cast(typing.Type[T], new_model)
```

Constructing objects by typed helper function:

```py
# not helping
def construct_objects(cls: typing.Type[T]) -> QuerySet[T]:
    return QuerySet[T](cls)


class Metaclass(typing.Generic[T], BaseMetaclass):
    def __new__(  # type: ignore
            mcs: typing.Any, name: str, bases: typing.Any, attrs: dict
    ):
        new_model = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)  # type: ignore
        if hasattr(new_model, 'Meta'):
            new_model.objects = construct_objects(new_model)
        return new_model
```

Typed descriptor:

```py
# not helping
class ObjectsDescriptor(typing.Generic[T]):

    def __init__(self, value: typing.Type[T]):
        self.value = QuerySet[T](value)

    def __get__(self, instance, owner) -> QuerySet[T]:
        return self.value


class Metaclass(typing.Generic[T], BaseMetaclass):
    def __new__(  # type: ignore
            mcs: typing.Any, name: str, bases: typing.Any, attrs: dict
    ):
        new_model = super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs)  # type: ignore
        if hasattr(new_model, 'Meta'):
            new_model.objects = ObjectsDescriptor(new_model)
        return new_model
```

It seems I have to annotate either `NewBaseModel` or `Model` with `objects` property.
But I rely on this before class instantiation, so no idea how to generic type class variable with generic class (itself) that is accessed as a class var so without calling **init** and **new**.

```py
class NewBaseModel(typing.Generic[T], BaseModel, metaclass=Metaclass):
    pass
    # if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
    #     objects: QuerySet[T] < here


class Model(typing.Generic[T], NewBaseModel):
    if typing.TYPE_CHECKING:
        objects: QuerySet[T]  # or here

    class Meta:
        concrete = True

    def __init__(self: T):  # adding new or init does not help
        pass
```

Annotating Metaclass with Generic and setting objects classvar there.

```py
class Metaclass(typing.Generic[T], BaseMetaclass):
    objects: QuerySet[T]

    def __new__(  # type: ignore
            mcs: typing.Type[T], name: str, bases: typing.Any, attrs: dict
    ) -> typing.Type[T]:
        new_model = typing.cast(typing.Type[T], super().__new__(mcs, name, bases, attrs))  # type: ignore
        if hasattr(new_model, 'Meta'):
            # new_model= typing.cast(typing.Type[T], new_model)
            reveal_type(new_model)
            new_model.objects = QuerySet[T](new_model)
            reveal_type(new_model.objects)
        return new_model
```

Although it's an improvement(?) cause: Revealed type is 'T`1' instead of Any but this suggests that T is never resolved and it's still useless and gives errors like:

```py
def process_mymodel(model: MyModel):
    pass
```

Argument 1 to "process_mymodel" has incompatible type "T"; expected "MyModel"

Comment: I think the problem is that your _metaclass_ isn't generic, because `objects` is a class attribute of `NewBaseModel`.

Comment: @Jasmijn thanks for tip but I also tried that -> updated the question with things I tried but they do not help.

Comment: And have you tried `objects: typing.ClassVar[QuerySet[T]]` in `class Model`?